# Redux: Handling State between Multiple Routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux

I have to say this is a great way to manage your state for your application. But I have a few questions that I cannot seem to find an answer to anywhere on the internet.

Handling your state across multiple routes, meaning:

I have my state, looks something like this:

```
{
    user: {},
    routing: {}
}
```

And I have a few different pages, meaning that it adds (for example) `todos` which only matters in the `/todo` route. How is something like this handled? Or do I not even include this in redux. I was thinking I could add an object for every route, but that would get messy, quickly. Unless this is the suggested route to take?

I am looking for the correct "redux" answer to this. Would I just not include those values in Redux, or would I create only for every route and just nest the values as I went? Anything is helpful at this point, because I'm running out of an ideas for this.

Thank you everyone!

---

Edit!

Just to reply to what has been going on in the comments. This is what my state looks like:

```
{
  "routing": {
    "changeId": 1,
    "path": "/",
    "state": null,
    "replace": false
  },
  "todos": {
    "visibilityFilter": "SHOW_ALL",
    "todos": [
      {
        "text": "Use Redux - This is the initial state.",
        "completed": false,
        "id": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  "requests": {
    "isFetching": false,
    "data": {}
  }
}
```

Pulled almost straight from redux, the routing object is from `react-router` so this is leading me to believe I don't really need this. But I'm just trying to figure out how keep things clean and how to structure my actions / reducers for a giant application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The beauty of redux is the composability of the reducers. This means you can store all kinds of information in there, while handling it all quite separately. Here's some oversimplified and generic advice.

1. Store all app state in Redux. That means a `todos` property might be there while not on a route that needs it (but it might not be populated).
2. Decouple *routes* from *data*. A route is a method for bundling up a bunch of view elements together. Those view elements may in turn have data requirements, but they are independent of whatever route (or routes!) in which they appear. Your store should have a shape that represents your business domain.

If your application has various entities like todo items, calendar entries, and chat messages, your "model" may look like this:

```
todos:
  todo1:
    name: String
    completed: boolean
  ...
threads:
  thread1:
    participants: [ ... ]
    messages: [ ... ]
  ...
events:
  event:
    date: Date
    todos: [ 'todo1', 'todo2' ]
  ...
users:
  ...
...
```

We may have a "todos" route where we focus on todos, but that is simply a representation of some of our domain data. A `TodoList` component will need data and hook up to the store to get what it needs. A route on which it appears may trigger an action to request the data - or it may come from someplace else entirely. Browsing to a different route starts the process again, but only for whatever data is needed then.

3. Cache data in the store. If a user clicks from route A to route B and then back again, a server call to re-fetch all of the data probably isn't necessary. Cache invalidation is beyond the scope of this post.

Comment: So just to clear this up in my head, only keep business related items within the store. That makes sense, and yea cache invalidation isn't related to this at all haha. But thank you! This makes much more sense, I'm just going to keep it all separate. I'm just keeping in mind like an app that could a ton of data. I'm talking 30+ page application that has sub routes, and more. That is where I begin to worry...

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "business related items", but if you mean "state that's not UX" then yes (there are probably occasional exceptions). The number of pages or the depth of the routes isn't what's relevant - it's the number of listeners, which should be limited to one route at a time anyway. So I can help, what are you worried about, specifically? Code complexity or frailty or memory or something else?

Comment: I was just worried about the size of the state and dirty checking that could be happening. So the bigger the state, the more power it needs to run (obviously). I'm just trying to avoid slow downs and what not. I am coming from an Angular background, so dirty checking and watchers are a big thing in my head. That and according to redux docs, you always create a brand new object vs. just modifying the current object. Which I understand but what if you have say 30+ objects plus nested objects, what happens to performance?

Comment: I come from an Angular world, too - that's where 90% of my SO rep comes from. I can say that dirty checking and watchers are far *less* of a big deal in a React+Flux/Redux kind of world out of the box, particularly when coupled with something like [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/), which I definitely recommend. You're never actually "watching" anything for changes; instead, a store *says* that it changed by virtue of an action being fired. Aside from memory, the size of the object shouldn't matter - particularly with immutable objects.

Comment: Ah! I read that Immutable.js is almost required in a setup with Redux mainly for state management. I'll read how to get that integrated, I'm working on a little kit and just kind of winging it when it comes to how things work and what not. I understand the basic lifecycle and what not so, but a second set of eyes on this is definitely helpful. Thanks man! I'll check that out.

Comment: I disagree with point 3 "Cache data in the store". Redux store represents state of your application, if you use it as cache you're leaking out single component state to global redux store, dispatching an action doesn't affect application anyhow, it affects only 1 component. If you add routing there, dispatching an action affects only 1 component if you're on a correct route. Having redux store as cache store means that your redux store doesn't have single responsibility. Caching should be done within a module that does fetching

Comment: @alucic I think you're getting too hung up on the word "cache". I was simply saying that if the data is already in your store because it's part of the application state, there is no need to re-fetch the data when returning back to that route (unless your use case demands the fresher data). I am not suggesting anyone use it as a caching layer for http calls.